# jQuery draggable clone doesn't stay where it is dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI to clone a element from a div, drag and release at another div.
At first time I drop the cloned element, it change the position and goes far from where was released. But, it still draggable and stay where must be at the other times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: "crosshair",
        containment: 'frame',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var cloned = $(ui.helper).clone();
            cloned.attr("id", "clonedElem" + counter);
            var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();

            var draggableOffset = ui.helper.offset(),
                droppableOffset = $(this).offset(),
                left = draggableOffset.left - droppableOffset.left,
                top = draggableOffset.top - droppableOffset.top;

            cloned.css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "left": left,
                "top": top
            });

            cloned.attr("visible", "true");

            cloned.draggable({
                containment: 'parent',
                stop:function(ev, ui) {
                    console.log("aqui");
                }
            });
            $("#frame").append(cloned);
            counter++;
        }
    });  

    $("#frame").droppable({
        accept: ".drag",
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="options" class="list-group col-md-1">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="drag1" class="drag ui-draggable">
                <h1>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="drag2" class="drag ui-draggable">
                <h1>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-magnet"></span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="drag3" class="drag ui-draggable">
                <h1>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="drag4" class="drag ui-draggable">
                <h1>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="drag5" class="drag ui-draggable">
                <h1>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tower"></span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="drag6" class="drag ui-draggable">
                <h1>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="frame" class="col-md-11 ui-droppable" style="border: 2px #000 solid; height: 558px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is good, but you're applying to the wrong event. The `$(this)` you're using to set `droppableOffset` is actually the `draggable`, because you're calling it on the `stop` event of `draggable`. It should be on the `drop` event of the `droppable`. Also, avoid using top as it is a property of the `window` object, so it'll give unwanted behavior. This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: "crosshair",
        containment: 'frame',

    });  

    $("#frame").droppable({
        accept: ".drag",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var cloned = $(ui.helper).clone();
            cloned.attr("id", "clonedElem" + counter);
            var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();

            var draggableOffset = ui.helper.offset(),
                droppableOffset = $(this).offset(),
                left = draggableOffset.left - droppableOffset.left,
                thisTop = draggableOffset.top - droppableOffset.top;

            cloned.css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "left": left,
                "top": thisTop
            });

            cloned.attr("visible", "true");

            cloned.draggable({
                containment: 'parent',
                stop:function(ev, ui) {
                    console.log("aqui");
                }
            });
            $("#frame").append(cloned);
            counter++;
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vv6rzc4L/

Comment: offset method looks little long but saved my day, jquery ui should consider this requirement so that longer codes can be reduced